# Published App but Play Store not showing update on any device

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services, store

I've Published my updated app to play store. I've also updated the build number and name before uploading. But still play store is not showing the updated version in any device.

Comment: Have you changed the app version in your apk ?

Comment: Did you mean Build Version ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This happens when your device has a debug build installed and if you
> look your app in playstore then it does not show `Update` button
> instead of `Open` button

**Solutions:-**

1. Uninstall app from device and download it from playstore on the same device.
2. Next time before you update on playstore , download app from playstore and when the app gets updated on playstore then check the app on playstore it will show update button

Answer (score 0):

Go in the **build.gradle** and set the version code and name inside the defaultConfig element

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Here, update your version code and name.